# CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have two location managers, one on a view controller with a map the other one in a separate controller that I present as modal. The issue is that every time I present that modal controller, I get a crash with the following backtrace.

I've tried setting delegates to nil, or setting the actual location manager to nil on viewWillDisappear and then re-initialising them on viewWillAppear, but still the issue persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#0  0x9105fafa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x91060267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x016d313a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01636580 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x01635db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x01635ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x026a6879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#7  0x026a693e in GSEventRun ()
#8  0x003e1a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#9  0x000028b2 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffeca4) at /Users/penushlievm/Desktop/DailyPlanner 2/DailyPlanner 2/main.m:16
#10 0x00002825 in start ()
```

Comment: why do you have two? and what do you mean by "modal" ?

Comment: Can you edit and add the code you have in viewWillAppear / viewWillDisappear et. al.?

Comment: @MJB I am presenting the second controller as a modal view controller.

Comment: add breakpoint in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear and go step by step...you can figure out at which point program crashes.

Comment: Having 2 location managers wont crash your program, it will just make the readings wrong and other stuff, you crash lies somewhere else, add an exception breakpoint so that you see why it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using one location manager globally instead of two.